# Why is my java program continuously running and not finishing the main method?

Tags: java, while-loop, runtime

I'm writing a program that solves a square root. The program seems to work properly up until it reaches the `while ((x1-x2)>dif)` loop and then runs forever with out returning the final `x2`.
Thanks for reading!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab13 {
static double getSqrt(double s) {
    double dif = .000001;
    double S = 0;
    if (s == 0)
        return 0;
    double a = s;
    int n = 0;
    if (a >= 100) {
        while (a >= 100) {
            a /= 100;
            n++;
        }
    }
    else {
        while (a < 1) {
            a *= 100;
            n --;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a + " " + n);

    if (a < 10) {
        S = 2*Math.pow(10, n);
    }
    else {
        S = 6*Math.pow(10, n);
    }
    System.out.println(S);

    double x1, x2;
    x1=S;
    System.out.println(x1);
    x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
    System.out.println(x2);

    while ((x1-x2)>dif) {
      x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
    }
    System.out.println(x2);
    return x2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter n (negative to stop):");
    double n = in.nextDouble();
    while (n >= 0) {
        System.out.println(getSqrt(n));
        System.out.println();Math.sqrt(n);

        System.out.print("Enter n(negative to stop):");
        n = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(getSqrt(n));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to what you're doing.

```
x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
```

The right side of that expression is constant inside the loop, so the value of x2 never changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((x1-x2)>dif) {
  x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
}
```

The trouble is that `x2` is being updated but `x1` is not. For [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) to work `x1` needs to be the previous guess, but since it's not being updated `x1` is perpetually the *first guess*.

```
while ((x1-x2)>dif) {
  double prev = x2;

  x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
  x1 = prev;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((x1-x2)>dif) {
    x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
}
```

Neither `x1` nor `dif` nor `s` do not change inside the `while`. `x2` changes from the original value but its value is set to the same value in each iteration (since it depends only of `x1` and `s`). So either the loop runs just once or it will run forever.

Why do you expect this not to fail?

Comment: HA! Glad you added that last comment. I just love sarcastic comments.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because in your code

```
while ((x1-x2)>dif) {
  x2 = (0.5)*(x1+(s/x1));
}
```

x2 never increases, never changes its values, `x1-x2` remains constant and > diff, thus you never exit out of the loop